# Concurrent Modification Exception in Callable class

Tags: java, concurrency, future, callable

I'm trying to split a list of objects within smaller sublist and to process them separately on different threads. So I have following code:

```
        List<Instance> instances = xmlInstance.readInstancesFromXml();
        List<Future<List<Instance>>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

        int nThreads = 4;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

        final List<List<Instance>> instancesPerThread = split(instances, nThreads);

        for (List<Instance> instancesThread : instancesPerThread) {
            if (instancesThread.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            Callable<List<Instance>> callable = new MyCallable(instancesThread);
            Future<List<Instance>> submit = executor.submit(callable);
            futureList.add(submit);
        }

        instances.clear();

        for (Future<List<Instance>> future : futureList) {
            try {
                final List<Instance> instancesFromFuture = future.get();
                instances.addAll(instancesFromFuture);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the MyCallable class :

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<List<Instance>> {

    private List<Instance> instances;

    public MyCallable (List<Instance> instances) {
        this.instances = Collections.synchronizedList(instances);
    }


    @Override
    public List<Instance> call() throws Exception {

        for (Instance instance : instances) {
            //process each object and changing some fields;
        }

        return instances;
    }

}
```

Split method(It's split an given list in given number of list, also trying to have almost same size on each sublist) :

```
public static List<List<Instance>> split(List<Instance> list, int nrOfThreads) {
        List<List<Instance>> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        final int nrOfItems = list.size();
        int minItemsPerThread = nrOfItems / nrOfThreads;
        int maxItemsPerThread = minItemsPerThread + 1;
        int threadsWithMaxItems = nrOfItems - nrOfThreads * minItemsPerThread;
        int start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfThreads; i++) {
            int itemsCount = (i < threadsWithMaxItems ? maxItemsPerThread : minItemsPerThread);
            int end = start + itemsCount;
            parts.add(list.subList(start, end));
            start = end;
        }

        return parts;
    }
```

So, when I'm trying to execute it, I'm getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException  on this line `for (Instance instance : instances) {`, can somebody give any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: This happens when you modify the list while you iterate over it.

Comment: Using an iterator will help?

Comment: An Iterator only helps if you do the modifications through this iterator. Can you make a copy of the list to iterate over it?

Comment: changed it to : `List<Instance> temp = new ArrayList<>(instances);`  and using iterator to iterate through it, and getting exception only on some threads, not at all...

Comment: Please include the code for the `split` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MyCallable (List<Instance> instances) {
    this.instances = Collections.synchronizedList(instances);
}
```

Using `synchronizedList` like this doesn't help you in the way you think it might.

It's only useful to wrap a list in a `synchronizedList` at the time you create it (e.g. `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`. Otherwise, the underlying list is directly accessible, and thus accessible in an unsynchronized way.

Additionally, `synchronizedList` only synchronizes for the duration of individual method calls, not for the whole time while you are iterating over it.

The easiest fix here is to take a copy of the list *in the constructor*:

```
    this.instances = new ArrayList<>(instances);
```

Then, nobody else has access to that list, so they can't change it while you are iterating it.

This is different to taking a copy of the list in the `call` method, because the copy is done in a single-threaded part of the code: no other thread can be modifying it while you are taking that copy, so you won't get the `ConcurrentModificationException` (you *can* get a CME in single-threaded code, but not using this copy constructor). Doing the copy in the `call` method means the list is iterated, in exactly the same way as with the `for` loop you already have.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it worked... the problem was that I made copy in run method :))